# How to perform `or` in jq?

Tags: jq, multipart-alternative

I got the following results.

```
$ jq '.[].a,.[].b' <<< '[{"a": 1},  {"b": 2}]'
1
null
null
2
$ jq '.[] | select(.a or .b)' <<< '[{"a": 1},  {"b": 2}]'
{
  "a": 1
}
{
  "b": 2
}
```

But I want to search either "a" and "b" and the output that I would like is this.

```
1
2
```

What is the proper way to perform this `or` operation? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use alternate operator (`//`):

```
$ jq '.[] | .a//.b' <<< '[{"a": 1},  {"b": 2}]'
1
2
```